# Get last values of n distinct fields

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with mysqli query. I have a table that contains fields user,card,action... like so

```
id   user   card   action   time
1    1      1      1        5
2    1      1      2        6
3    1      1      3        7
4    2      1      1        8
```

I need to get an array of **10 last users** with all of their actions, like so

```
array(
  2 => array(1),    
  1 => array(1,2,3)
)
```

I tried using distinct but it only returns one action for each user and making multiple queries for it is probably not the best solution, i cant think of anything else to try. Maybe the combined query is needed but i cant figure out how to do it.

Thank you!

Okay, using the help i had i made my own query but for some reason, it fails to slelect the highest value of time, everything else is working. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68751d/1

```
    $m = new_m();
    if ($s = $m -> prepare("SELECT user, group_concat(action) as actions, time FROM cards_actions_data WHERE card=? GROUP BY user ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 10")) {
        $s -> bind_param('i', $card);
        $s -> execute();
        $s -> bind_result($user,$actions,$time);
        while($s -> fetch()){
            $users[$user]['time'] = $time; 
            $users[$user]['actions'] = $actions;
        }
        $s -> close();

    }
    pre($users);
    pre($m);
    $m -> close();

    return $users;
```

Comment: i tried using distinct but it only returns one action for each user, i cant think of anything else to try...

Comment: How do you define "*last users*"?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, i also have a time field for every action user has made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i understand you may looking for `GROUP_CONCAT`  . try this :

```
 SELECT user , group_concat(`action`) actions , max(`time`) `time`
 FROM table1
 GROUP BY user
 ORDER BY `time` DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

[**LOOK demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa20f/4)

Comment: Thank you, it worked but with only small problem. I also have a time field and i want the last user that made the action be the first. prepare("SELECT user, group_concat(`action`) as actions FROM cards_actions_data WHERE card=? GROUP BY user ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 10")

Comment: Worked on fiddle but not for me, need to look whats wrong with my query. Thank you a lot! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87962/1

Comment: Its really weird, i copied the query directly into phpmyadmin but the result is flawed only in my pc. It dosent show the highest time value.

Comment: Just edited my original post

Comment: here is the fiddle fail: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68751d/1

Comment: I figured it out, instead of time, i need to select max(time) :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cb69/1

Comment: you welcome :) just be sure to accept answer .

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT   user, GROUP_CONCAT(action)
FROM     my_table NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT DISTINCT user FROM my_table ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
         ) t
GROUP BY user
```